# How to populate UL from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-lists

I have an `UL` in my ASP.net page:

```
<ul id="ulO" runat="server">
</ul>
```

Code-behind:

```
foreach (string wrWG in workGroupLists)
{
    // add each "wrWG" as a list item to the `ulO`
}
```

I tried using `asp:Repeater` to populate but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
foreach (string wrWG in workGroupLists)
{
  HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
  li.InnerText = wrWG; 
  ulO.Controls.Add(li);
}
```